# Count how many times any value appears in a combination of columns but not in other columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
A   B   C
1   2   
    3   4
1       5
1   2   4
1       2
1
```

I want to return the amount of times any value appears in a combination of two columns but not the third column. The numeric values in this case are arbitrary. I just care about counting instances.

In other words:

1.) How many times does any value appear in column A and column B but not column C?

2.) How many times does any value appear in column B and column C but not column A?

3.) How many times does any value appear in column A and column C but not in column B?

My expected answers based on the mock data I have given above:

> ```
> 1.) 1 (row 1)
> 2.) 1 (row 2)
> 3.) 2 (rows 3 and 5)
> ```

Comment: One idea: If you run `df.isna()` on your dataframe, you'll get a dataframe of true and false values. Then, you can use `groupby()` and `count()` to obtain a count of how many times each type of condition occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `isna` to create a boolean DataFrame. Then filter the rows that have only one NaN value (so that we exclude the last row). Finally `sum` vertically:

```
df_na = df.isna()
df_na[df_na.sum(axis=1).eq(1)].sum()
```

Output:

```
A    1
B    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Then for example, column "A" doesn't have a value while the other two have values once, "B" doesn't have a value while the other two have twice, etc.

Comment: I'm a little confused here, I am having a hard time interpreting the output

Comment: @Melderon each number corresponding to a column name in the output is the number of times that column has no value while the others had a value.